# How do I name the dimensions in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am stuck on what ought to be fairly obvious, but...I've got dataframe that I created by importing a CSV with no headers. I can't seem to figure out how to name my columns now. I've found lots of instructions for creating new dataframes or importing data with headers, but not for adding column/dimension names once my data is imported.

Comment: if you look at the help for `?data.frame`, under the `see also:` section it points you to `names` and `row.names`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`names(df) <- c("col1", "col2", ...)`

`colnames(df) <- ...` will also work, since data.frames can be treated as matrices is many cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
> a = sample(LETTERS, 10)
> b = sample(LETTERS, 10)
> c = sample(LETTERS, 10)

> D = data.frame(a, b, c)

> colnames(D) = c("colA", "colB", "colC")

> D
       colA colB colC
    1    H    M    Z
    2    F    U    O
    3    S    O    X
    4    K    I    L
    5    O    H    Q
```

Another way to do it: assign colnames one column at a time:

```
> # copy second column and bind it to "col_B"
> D$col_B = D[,2]

> # then delete original column (bound to "colB")
> D[,2] = NULL

> D
        colA colC col_B
    1    H    Z     M
    2    F    O     U
    3    S    X     O
    4    K    L     I
    5    O    Q     H
```

Comment: Your second way is not very efficient. You can simply do `names(D)[2] <- "col_B"` to rename a single column.